# Как задать форматирование строки чтобы часть после запятой не выводилась если равна нулю?

Tags: java, android

Используя

```
String.format("", vol);
```

При числе 1.57689 должно быть выведено "1.5"

При числе 1.0 должно быть выведено "1" без нуля в конце

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Пример:

```
private static String OUTPUT_FORMAT = "#.##";
private static double EXAMPLE_VALUE = 3.140;
...
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(OUTPUT_FORMAT);
String output = formatter.format(EXAMPLE_VALUE);

System.out.println("Output = " + output);
```